# Why doesn't Strict Mode throw Syntax Error on duplicated property names?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

In JavaScript, Strict Mode is supposed to throw Syntax Error if we try to define object with duplicated properties, like this:

```
const foo = {a: 1, a: 2};
```

Call me crazy, but I remember it did. Today I was in shock to find out that it doesn't at least in newest Chrome and Firefox on macOS.

```
function crazy() {
    'use strict';

    const badboy = {a: 1, a: 2};

    return badboy;
}

console.log(crazy().a); // prints 2
```

What happened?

Comment: It's ES6 - try it in an ES5 strict environment.

Comment: It looks like they allowed it because of the ellipsis syntax: `{...foo, ...bar}`. I'm sad for the old-fashioned literal, but with ellipsis I agree it makes more sense to allow duplicates.